# Setting Tags for Content Controls in a Word Document for Programmatically Updating Values

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I'm working on a project where I need to programmatically update the values of Content Controls in a Word document. I've successfully inserted Content Controls and tried to set tags for them but encountered some issues.

Here's the code

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GatherData();
    string docxFilePath = Path.Combine(executablePath, "CAR_Form.docx");
    string pdfFilePath = Path.Combine(executablePath, "CAR_Form.pdf");

    // Load the DOCX template
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docxFilePath, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

        // Define a list of tag-value pairs
        List<(string tag, string value)> tagValuePairs = new List<(string tag, string value)>
        {
            ("Respondent", respondent),
            ("GroupSec", group),
            ("IssueDate", issueDate),
            ("ResponseDate", responseDate),
            ("Requestor", requestor),
            ("CompanyDept", companyDept),
            ("ApprovedBy", approvedBy),
            ("CARNo", carNumber),
            ("ProblemDesc", problemDesc)
        };

        int emptyFieldCount = tagValuePairs.Count(pair => string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.value));
        if (emptyFieldCount > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, $"{emptyFieldCount} empty field(s) detected. Please provide a value for all placeholders.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        // Iterate through content controls and update them based on the tag-value pairs
        foreach (SdtElement contentControl in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
        {
            var tag = contentControl.SdtProperties.Elements<Tag>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (tag != null)
            {
                string tagValue = tag.Val;
                var matchingPair = tagValuePairs.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.tag == tagValue);
                Console.WriteLine($"Tag in Word: {tagValue}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Matching Pair: {matchingPair.tag} - {matchingPair.value}");
                if (matchingPair != default((string, string)))
                {
                    // Traverse nested content controls to find the SdtContentRun
                    SdtContentRun contentRun = contentControl.Descendants<SdtContentRun>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (contentRun == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ContentRun is null, checking nested controls...");
                        foreach (var innerControl in contentControl.Descendants<SdtElement>())
                        {
                            contentRun = innerControl.Descendants<SdtContentRun>().FirstOrDefault();
                            if (contentRun != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("ContentRun found in nested control.");
                                break; // Exit the loop once contentRun is found
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (contentRun != null)
                    {
                        Text text = contentRun.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
                        if (text != null)
                        {
                            text.Text = matchingPair.value;
                            Console.WriteLine($"Updated text to: {matchingPair.value}");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ContentRun is still null, check your document structure.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Save and close the modified document
        doc.Save();
        doc.Dispose();

        SaveAsPDF(docxFilePath, pdfFilePath);
    }

}
```

*Problems*

1. **Inserting Content Controls:**

- I've opened my Word document and inserted Content Controls via the "Developer" tab.
- I've chosen Content Controls (Plain Text) on the data I need to capture.

2. **Setting Tags:**

- To identify and manipulate these Content Controls programmatically, I've tried to set tags for them.
- In the "Developer" tab, I accessed the "Properties" dialog and entered unique tag names for each Content Control in the "Tag" field.

3. **Code for Updating Content:**

- I've written code in C# to open the Word document, access the Content Controls, and update their values based on the tags I've set.
- My code iterates through the Content Controls and attempts to locate them by their tags.

The problem is that when I run my code, it doesn't seem to find the Content Controls based on the tags I've set. Specifically, the **`SdtContentRun`** elements within the Content Controls are null, and my code doesn't update the values.

**Troubleshooting:**

- I've double-checked the tags in my Word document and the tags in my code, and they match.
- I've ensured that my Content Controls are not deeply nested and are at the expected level within the document structure.

What could be causing my code to not find and update the Content Controls as expected?
Are there any additional considerations or common pitfalls when working with Content Controls and tags in Word documents?

Comment: AFAICR the term "Run" in SdtContentRun is a bit misleading, because if the SDT is a Block-level SDT I think it will have an SdtCOntentBlock rather than an sdtContentRun (despite the fact that in the XML they are both represented by an sdtContent element and may have w:r elements inside. But I wonder whether the documents you are modifying are *always* going to be opened in Word as the next step in your process, because if so, it might be a lot simpler to map your SDTs to a Custom XML Part, write/modify the data in the part, and leave Word to update the text in the SDTs when it opens the doc.

Comment: BTW, I tested with a cut-down version of your code and it was definitely finding the Content Controls that I had actually given a tag name in WOrd itself. It was actually the SdtContentRun elements it wasn't finding.

Comment: The use of "Run" in SdtContentRun can be misleading, especially with block-level Structured Document Tags (SDTs) possibly having SdtContentBlock. This highlights a terminology concern in the WordprocessingDocument API. The suggestion of Custom XML Parts is intriguing. If the Word document is consistently accessed in Word post-alteration, Word can manage text updates in SDTs automatically, offering a viable solution. However, it's crucial to consider the project's broader context.

Comment: The original coding approach suits my needs if the document must be processed programmatically without additional Word interactions.

Validates the difficulty in locating SdtContentRun elements within the Content Controls, a specific problem that was mentioned in the original query. This is consistent with the main issue, which is that SdtContentRun elements aren't discovered but Content Controls with tag names set in Word are.

Comment: I'm now not sure what the question is. The original question seemed to be "I'm applying tags to the Content Controls in the document, but my code isn't finding either the tags or the ContentControlRuns." When I tested, it was finding Content Controls with tags, but SdtContentRun was always null (with my test document), whereas SdtContentBlock was not.